# getting file path without loading file in memory in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filepicker

I am trying to make an app for sending files to my remote server via ssh in flutter. My idea is to get the path of selected file and pass it over to ssh.
I am using file picker plugin in flutter to select file, but it taking file to memory before getting file path, for large files this is taking time.is there any way to get the path of file only without taking file to memory ?

Comment: What is it doing with this file in memory? I see no reason.

Comment: @blackapps my need is to get the path of selected file instantly..i am handling with files greater than 1GB ..which taking lot of time

Comment: You did not answer my question. I already knew what you want. I still dont know why it is put in memory.

Comment: Please, can you copy the piece of code where you load these files?

Comment: @SylvainL.Kamdem https://bin.disroot.org/?ead174a5d5d9052a#ATuPe4U6RAn4rHT9jWUD1FfooTU9uupukQd7fudUDDUZ

Comment: @blackapps its doing nothing in memory

Comment: @SylvainL.Kamdem i tried it from here https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/blob/master/example/lib/src/file_picker_demo.dart

Comment: You are right, I tried the example app with some big files and it took time. I had this line in the debugger console for every selected file: `I/FilePickerUtils( 2296): Caching file from remote/external URI`

Comment: @SylvainL.Kamdem is there any way can get file path without loading it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a method in this project [flutter file utils](https://github.com/MohamSayed/flutter_file_utils/blob/master/lib/src/file_system_utils.dart)
there is a method call list_file in this

Comment: So how can we get the path to the files we selected? (like filepicker)

Comment: what we getting is a list of file paths (of selected files)